# Quill: Which method called when blot changed?

Tags: quill, parchment

I need to do something when text, wrapped with my own blot, changed.

From [parchment documentation](https://github.com/quilljs/parchment/#blots) i got that method `update` will called when blot changes.
I try to use it in [code](https://codepen.io/szobov/pen/vZRmGK), but this method does't called when text, wrapped with my blot, changes.

May be I use this method incorrect? Or I should use another method?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [text-change](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#text-change) event:

```
this.quill.on('text-change', (range, oldRange, source) => {

 // Returns the leaf Blot at the specified index within the document
 let [leaf, offset] = this.quill.getLeaf(range.index); // Experimental API

  if(leaf.domNode.nodeName === 'yourBlotTag') {
    //Do something
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it soon.
By the way, it would be better to provide an example to the answer on any sandbox platform, like [codepen](https://codepen.io) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).